# Stackoverflow Careers Site not pulling all Github open source contributions

Tags: discussion, jobs, open-source, github

When I click the Github button under Open Source Contributions, I only see my own repos and a couple of the repos that I have made contributions to; there are about 5+ other repos that I have made contributions to which are not showing up at all, and I can't add them manually using "other".  Furthermore, there is no difference in the couple of non-owned repos I have contributed to that DO show up, and the others that DON'T show up; I made just as many, if not more, contributions to the ones that are missing.

How can I fix this?  Is there no other way to manually add Github open source contributions?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by making sure I was a **public** member of the organizations that didn't show up in Career's list. By default membership is private.

Comment: Thanks; I'm sure this would work in the situation you mentioned.  In this case, though, everything was already public.  There were various Pull Requests, helpful Issues opened, and numerous other things, all on public Github repos, and it didn't include them.  Perhaps it's just choosy or only goes back so far date-wise.